# How to spilt list<ID> values

Tags: apex

In debug log i am getting

```
selectedCategories = (01t90000003J9QwAAK, 01t90000003J9QxAAK)
```

I need first record field Site__c should have `01t90000003J9QwAAK` and 2nd record field Site_c should have `01t90000003J9QxAAK`. Field `Site__c` is a text field.

How to split selectedCategories.

```
     public List<ID> selectedCategories {
        get {
            if (selectedCategories == null) {
                selectedCategories = new List<ID>();
            }
            return selectedCategories ;
        }
        set;
    }

   List<Date__c> accs=new List<Date__c>();
   for (AccountWrapper wrap : wrappers)
   {
   wrap.acc.Site__c =  string.valueof(selectedCategories);
   accs.add(wrap.acc);
   }
   insert accs;
```

Comment: Can we use spilt method for selectedCategories .

Comment: `selectedCategories[i]` will return i-th element, starting from 0

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that you will always have the same number of records in your account list, and that each one will be assigned a value at their given index in the list provided, you can change your loop to a [`for`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for.htm) loop and assign each one by an index value.

```
List<Date__c> accs = new List<Date__c>();

// replace foreach with for to get access to a index variable 
for (Integer i = 0; i < wrappers.size(); i++) // iterate over all wrappers 
{
    // for the current wrapper, assign them a string casted value based on the same index of the selectedCategories variable 
    wrappers[i].acc.Site__c = String.valueOf(selectedCategories.get(i));
    // add it to the list 
    accs.add(wrappers[i].acc);
}

insert accs;
```

---

Frankly, I'd avoid doing this, and instead, store the selected category in a [`Map<Id, Id>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm), with the first key as the account Id, and the second key as the category id.

Somewhere in your code, these values get assigned, using [`put`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_put):

```
selectedCategories.put(account.Id, someCatergoryId);
```

And later, you iterate over these values, and fetch which one was picked for which account, using [`get`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_get).

```
List<Date__c> accs = new List<Date__c>();

for (AccountWrapper wrap : wrappers)
{
    wrap.acc.Site__c = selectedCategories.get(wrap.acc.Id); // returns the value, which is set to the category id 
    accs.add(wrap.acc);
}
insert accs;
```

Comment: Hi battery.. How i want is .. if selectedCategories contains 2 elements and wrappers.size() = 2, the first element should get inserted as a record with elements present in wrappers.size(). And 2nd element in selectedCategories should be inserted as a record with elements present in wrappers.size(). Currently only one element in selectedCategories is getting inserted..

Comment: wrappers.size() - I am able to insert. But i need to check selectedCategories.size() and each element of selectedCategories list should be inserted with  wrappers.size() . Ex selectedCategories = (1,2) and  wrappers.size() = 4. 1 should get inserted with wrappers.size() = 4 and 2  get inserted with wrappers.size() = 4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'splitting' is the concept that you're looking for.

Easiest way I can think of sequentially assigning items, from a list, inside of a loop, is to use `List.remove()`

```
List<Integer> test = new List<Integer>{5,6,7,8,9,10};

// Outputs 5, then 6, then 7, then 8, then 9, and finally 10
while(!test.isEmpty()){
    // When we remove the object at index 0 from a list, the object that was previously at
    //   index 1 becomes the new index 0.
    // It's important to perform a check for an empty array in each iteration,
    //   else, you have a high chance of getting a "list index out-of-bounds" exception
    system.debug(test.remove(0));
}
```